# how to expose a restful service inside a WPF project

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, web-services

I'm a bit of a newbie. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 for a desktop application, and I need to expose some data from there to websites in my LAN, but I have no idea how to.

I create an MVC2 project, I created a new controller and I can expose a simple "helloWorld" service like this:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult HolaMundo()
    {
        List<object> movies = new List<object>();

        movies.Add(new { Title = "Ghostbusters", Genre = "Comedy", Year = 1984 });
        movies.Add(new { Title = "Gone with Wind", Genre = "Drama", Year = 1939 });
        movies.Add(new { Title = "Star Wars", Genre = "Science Fiction", Year = 1977 });

        return Json(movies, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and it works: [image: picture that shows the service works]

How can I do it but in a wpf project? (Or how can I use this mvc project from the wpf project to get the same results?)

I'm just lost in an sea of information, I don't even know how to search for a solution for my problem.

Thanks for your patience, have a nice day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You typically don't *expose* a RESTful service from a WPF application. A WPF application is a client desktop application that is supposed to be run on an end-users client machine. A RESTful service is supposed to be exposed from a server that several clients can connect to - typically a web server.

You could indeed use WCF to create a REST service: http://www.infoworld.com/article/3061973/application-development/how-to-create-a-restful-service-in-wcf.html

...and host the WCF service in any .NET application including a WPF application: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758(v=vs.110).aspx

But the problem is that there is still no good way of exposing your WPF client application so that other clients can connect to it as it is a client application rather than a server application. So if you want to create a RESTful service I recommend you to take a look at either WCF or ASP.NET Web API: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api

You can then *consume* a REST service in a WPF application using the HttpClient client for example. There is an example of how to do this available here: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client. There is really no difference between consuming a REST service from a WPF application and any other managed (.NET) application.

Comment: Well, yes - "typically". Right now, I do want exactly this: expose a RESTful service from a WPF application. I am aware of the fact that this should be done with a service, but in this special case it does not fit.