# How to provide RESTful web service(s) from WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, rest, servicestack

Typically a WPF application is a consumer/client of a RESTful service(s) on a web server. I would like to have it reversed - WPF application should be able to expose an web API. This would be consumed by an web app.

The flow:

```
web app ---sends a command to--> WPF app
** WPF app makes a 'long running job' until its user decides to stop **
WPF app ---passes data back to--> web app
```

The communication should be in Json format. I have prepared [OpenAPI](https://swagger.io/specification/) (in [YAML](https://yaml.org/)) schema for it at the http://editor.swagger.io/. In the future it could be used to make changes to the WPF app's web API.

It allows to generate ASP.NET Core server c# code stub. What would be the requirements to run ASP.NET Core server in WPF and weither it would be light weight enough for use?

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

// somewhere in the WPF app: BuildWebHost(args).Run();
```

The code is auto-generated by https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen.

There is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52151412]) which failed to integrate ASP.NET Core 2.x into WPF application. Unfortunatelly, ASP.NET Core 3.0 and later will only run on .NET Core.

I have some bits here and there but not a working concept. My options could be:

- Use a 3rd party framework or library. Should be able to use OpenAPI/YAML schema or Swagger generated server stub code etc.

  - Could ServiceStack be the missing piece here?
- Integrate ASP.NET Core into WPF. Is it is even possible?
- Launch a separate web server (not a self-hosting) with web services from the WPF application. Sounds bad.
- Implement WCF web service(s) and requests.
- ...

**How to implement the web server/service(s) at WPF side? Maybe there is an existing 3rd party framework which could save me from reinventing the wheel?**

PS. There is a similar question [how to expose a restful service inside a WPF project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40979108) but it is outdated.

Comment: What makes you think the other question is outdated? It's a mere 2.5 years old, and the answer is still perfectly valid.

Comment: Okay the answer is not outdated. Are the options really limited to WCF and ASP.NET Web API?

Comment: *Maybe there is an existing 3rd party framework which could save me from reinventing the wheel?* There is. It's called ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Before you go down this route of trying to combine a desktop UI app with a web app.....why?! Why is this necessary? Why not just have them be two separate apps, and let them communicate via interprocess communication or message queues or a database or have the WPF app just be another client of the web app? Why make it difficult on yourself? But anyways, WPF is in .NET Core 3, so you should be able to self host an ASP.NET Core app in a WPF app if you're running on .NET Core 3.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The WPF app needs to provide an interface for 3rd party web app. Using (RESTful) web services could be a direct way to communicate. I am not aware of interprocess communication and message queues sounds a complex solution. I could be wrong. Please consider to elaborate your thoughts as an answer.

Comment: Does the WPF app itself truly need to provide an interface for a 3rd party app? Why can't you just have a separate web application dedicated to this purpose?

Comment: Because the WPF desktop app communicates with hardware and file/image processing which does not fit well as a web app.

Comment: I didn't say to get rid of the WPF app. I'm saying have them be two separate apps that then communicate with each other.

Comment: How could they be deployed together so that the WPF could start/stop of the web app? They should work in union and I am not sure which IPC would be the simplest to implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like your requirement:

> WPF application should be able to expose an web API. This would be consumed by an web app.

But then you're against the only solution that would make it possible:

> Launch a web server with web services from the WPF application. Sounds bad.

I'm not sure how else you're expecting being able to expose a Web API without launching a web server? Inside a UI App you'd want to launch a self-hosted Service.

#### Self Hosting

In ServiceStack you can just start a [self-hosted Service](https://docs.servicestack.net/self-hosting) in your WPF App which can either be a self-hosted .NET Framework HTTP Listener or an [ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework](https://docs.servicestack.net/templates-corefx) App. Both options Microsoft have said are going to be supported indefinitely, but .NET Framework is being phased out with ASP.NET Core 3.0 only going to run on .NET Core and .NET Framework stopping development at v4.x as [.NET 5 is just going to be the next version of .NET Core](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/).

But that shouldn't change what solutions are available to you now, if you need to run a Web Service in a WPF .NET Framework App you'll need to run a self-hosted .NET Framework HTTP Server which can either be a self-hosted HTTP Listener or ASP.NET Core (on .NET FX) App.

Comment: By launching a web server I meant to start a separate web server from the app. Something like when you start to debug a web app locally. I didn't mean the self-hosting :)

Comment: Can I use OpenAPI YAML file to generated some of the code? I found the ServiceStack Open API plugin https://docs.servicestack.net/openapi just the intention of it is unclear for me. Could I use it to modify a self-hosted web service in WPF? Sorry for the dumb questions, it is really a new world for me.

Comment: @JPollack No, Open API is just a Services Description language that clients can inspect to view APIs available by a server, it doesn't do anything like start a self-hosted HTTP Server which is what you need.