# How can I host a html/javascript page in my local client

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, self-hosting

I have a WPF client and I receive an HTML string including Javascript. Today I save it as a file and use Process.Start to launch it but is there a slim way of hosting it locally and doing Process.Start("http://localhost:999")?
I've been looking into WebServiceHost since we today use that to expose data as an OData feed, but unsure if that can actually run Javascript.
I'm not looking to host it in IIS.

Comment: You can use Nancy https://nancyfx.org and host your content with it directly from your WPF application, but it must have admin privileges or url reservation to work.

Comment: My users don't have admin rights I'm afraid. But I am trying HttpListener and that seems to be doing the trick.

Comment: `Nancy.Hosting.Self` uses `HttpListener` under the hood. Nancy is just convenient abstraction above things you digging to, you will need permissions anyway, this is windows security consideration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to provide RESTful web service(s) from WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442047/how-to-provide-restful-web-services-from-wpf-application)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I eventually went with HTTPListener which worked well (except for faulty windows example for the asynchronous call).